# Linq to sql type comparison

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have a varialbe name age and that's type is int?
My linq to sql query is:

```
from t in db.Profiles where t.age == age select t
```

having a comparison between int and int? at where clause. how the query processor of linq to sql will process in this case?

Answer (score 0):

If age is a type int? then I believe your query should read as follows:

```
from t in db.Profiles where t.age == age.Value select t
```

Comment: But if age is null then the NullPointException will be throwed

Comment: from t in db.Profiles where t.age == (age == null) ? null : age.Value select t